# Modifying class variable using @class decorator

Tags: python, class, class-method

```
import math as m

class Volume_cylinder_cp:
    # class variable
    pi = 3.14

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, radius, height, cp_milk):
        self.radius = radius
        self.height = height
        self.cp_milk = cp_milk

    # instance method
    def cal_vol(self):
        volume = m.pi * (pow(self.radius, 2)) * self.height
        print("Volume of cylinder: ", volume)
        return volume

    # instance method
    def cost_price(self):
        cp = Volume_cylinder_cp.cal_vol(self) * self.cp_milk
        print("Cost price: ", cp)

    # class method
       @classmethod
       def new_pi(cls, new_pi_val):
          # modify class variable
           cls.pi = new_pi_val

    vol_cp = Volume_cylinder_cp(2, 6, 10)

    # call instance method
    vol_cp.cal_vol()
    vol_cp.cost_price()

     print("after modifying the pi value")
    # call class method
    Volume_cylinder_cp.new_pi(3.2)
    vol_cp.cal_vol()
```

Modifying the value of class variable pi but getting same output after modifying.

and also can some please explain how to access volume value in cost_price instance method without accessing using class

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community! You are not using the pi value that you are modifying in your code, but the value present in "math" module that you are importing. A fix for your problem would be -

```
class Volume_cylinder_cp: # class variable pi = 3.14

    # ADDED THE CLASS VARIABLE IN THE 'CLASS SCOPE'
    pi=3.14

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, radius, height, cp_milk):
        self.radius = radius
        self.height = height
        self.cp_milk = cp_milk

    # instance method
    def cal_vol(self):
        # EDIT: accessing the class variable pi.
        volume = Volume_cylinder_cp.pi * (pow(self.radius, 2)) * self.height
        print("Volume of cylinder: ", volume)
        return volume

    # instance method
    def cost_price(self):
        cp = Volume_cylinder_cp.cal_vol(self) * self.cp_milk
        print("Cost price: ", cp)

    # class method
    @classmethod
    def new_pi(cls, new_pi_val):
        # modify class variable
        cls.pi = new_pi_val

vol_cp = Volume_cylinder_cp(2, 6, 10)

# call instance method
vol_cp.cal_vol()
vol_cp.cost_price()

print("after modifying the pi value")

# call class method
Volume_cylinder_cp.new_pi(3.2)
vol_cp.cal_vol()
```

The answer to your second question. You have not defined *cp* as a class attribute (or as a class variable). Therefore, you need to return the variable and store it somewhere to access it without the class.

```
# instance method
def cost_price(self):
    cp = Volume_cylinder_cp.cal_vol(self) * self.cp_milk
    print("Cost price: ", cp)
    return cp

cp = vol_cp.cost_price()
```

If it is made as a class attribute (or a class variable), it cannot be accessed without using the instance or the classname.